# Kotlin compiles to unrunnable javascript

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I have a project in kotlin (i.e. `sample-kotlin-project`) which is being compiled to javascript using gradle with the following gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js:$kotlin_version"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "4.1"
}

[compileKotlin2Js, compileTestKotlin2Js]*.configure {
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "commonjs"
}
```

After execution of `gradle clean build` I get the following artifacts:

1. `kotlin.js`
2. `sample-kotlin-project_main.js`

and import them into html file `index.html`:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="<path-to-target>/kotlin.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="<path-to-target>/sample-kotlin-project_main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both files are being found (meaning that all setup seems to be working just fine) except the following **error in console** from `sample-kotlin-project_main.js`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

which seems to be an issue for browser. Error occurs for the following lines in `sample-kotlin-project_main.js`:

```
  Kotlin.defineModule('sample-kotlin-project_main', _);
  return _;
}(module.exports, require('kotlin')));
```

My question is: **why does it happen** and **what should be done in order to fix this issue**?

Thanks a lot beforehand.

Comment: You need a module loader as well as the kotlin JS files.
You can pick AMD (RequireJS et. al), UMD or CommonJS .

Comment: see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-modules/working-with-modules.html

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Could you please elaborate on gradle integration to achieve this?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html#from-gradle

Comment: I already have that setting specified in `build.gradle`: `kotlinOptions.moduleKind = "commonjs"` and indeed I get `js` artifact of commonjs-style after gradle build. However my question is how it can be turned to something that can be run right away from browser?

Comment: anything new on this? I still cannot make it run using moduleKind. Made it work by removing     kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'amd/commonjs' from build.gradle and going to IDEA settings/preferences -> kotlin compiler -> Kotlin to Javascript section -> module kind -> Plain (put to global scope)

Comment: update: seems that when compiling to commonjs you don't need to import using <script>. Instead you must use require('your_kt_file') in other js files